# Using Arrays for Permissions

Tags: database-design

I am using Ruby on Rails, but I think this question could be applied to any database design. I am trying to develop my own permissions system.

Is it poor design to have an array of what a user can edit? i.e. a `User` has a column of `can_edit` with a value of `[Articles, Events, Costs]` or a `User` `can_view` with a value of  `[All]`.

And then I can just run a check on what is being edited. Or is this poor design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, your database design ought to be properly normalized.  That would mean that you shouldn't store multiple values in a single row.  You'll likely be much better served by a design that has three tables

- `Permission` has columns `permission_id` and `permission_type` and lists the valid permissions
- `User` has a `user_id` column and lists the value users
- `User_Permission` is a mapping table between the two.  It has columns `permission_id` and `user_id` both of which are defined as foreign keys to the `Permission` and `User` tables respectively

Comment: That was actually really helpful. However, I actually have a `Network` class too. Where a `User` belongs to a `Network`, and the `Permissions` would be specific for a given `Network`. A `User` can be a part of multiple `Networks` as well. Can you have a triple composite key, or is there another way to do that?

Or would I have a `User_Network` table and then a foreign key to a `Network_Permission` table?

Sorry if that doesn't make sense.

Comment: @JDewzy - If the `Permission` depends on the `Network`, then you would generally want a `User` table, a `User_Network` table, a `Network` table, a `Network_Permission` table, and a `Permission` table.

Comment: Then what connects the `Permission` to the `User`? Is a foreign key to `Network_Permission` present in the `User_Network` table?

Comment: @JDewzy - You'd join `User` to `Network` through `User_Network` and then join `Network` to `Permission` through `Network_Permission`.  There should not be a direct link between `User` and `Permission` if the permissions are assigned to networks not to users.

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion. I meant that a `User` may have `Edit Permission` in `Network 1` or `Delete Permission` in Network 2. But there can be custom `Permissions` in a given Network. Permissions are unique to a `Network`, but then are applied to a User in that `Network`. Maybe Role/Permission is a more accurate description? I do understand what you're saying about normalization and thanks! I think I described it poorly at first. So does this make more sense?